# Perl: How to retrieve field names when doing $dbh->selectall_..?

Tags: perl, dbi

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$sth->{NAME};
```

But how do you do that when:

```
$hr  = $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql,'pk_id');
```

There's no `$sth`, so how do you get the `$sth->{NAME}`? `$dbh->{NAME}` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're looking at a row, you can always use `keys %$row` to find out what columns it contains. They'll be exactly the same thing as `NAME` (unless you change `FetchHashKeyName` to `NAME_lc` or `NAME_uc`).

Comment: I'm outputting as an HTML table.  If I understand you correctly, you're saying to grab any record and use the keys from that record.

Comment: Yes.  Do a Data::Dumper on $hr and you'll get a better idea

Comment: @BillRuppert I understand the idea.  I think my question was less about a workaround and more, if DBI loads the NAME array into the database handle (or if there is a global statement handle I can interact with), since the docs say the selectall replaces the sth/prepare/execute.

Comment: @hobbs: you know as well as anyone that right and wrong are separate from should and does :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always prepare and execute the handle yourself, get the column names from it, and then pass the handle instead of the sql to selectall_hashref (e.g. if you want the column names but the statement may return no rows). Though you may as well call fetchall_hashref on the statement handle.